# Securing spring cloud config credentials using vault

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config, hashicorp-vault

I’m using spring-cloud-config-server with Git as a backend. I want to secure the git credentials of my private repository (username and password) to be served from the vault server.

I'm thinking to extend the `GitCredentialsProviderFactory` and create the credentials bean using `createFor()` with values from the `vault`. Is this a right approach or there are other recommended ways?

Comment: Have you get some success?

Comment: Yeah. I just posted it as an answer. The below solution addresses the question. I will keep it accepted until I find a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the `GitCredentialsProviderFactory` which I had thought of using. I used `MultipleJGitEnvironmentProperties` to create the GitPropert `bean`. And then supplied the credentials via the config values fetched from the vault.

```
@Bean MultipleJGitEnvironmentProperties createGitProps(){

        MultipleJGitEnvironmentProperties
                properties = new MultipleJGitEnvironmentProperties();
        properties.setUsername(username);
        properties.setUri(uri);
        properties.setSearchPaths(searchPath);
        properties.setPassword(password);
        properties.setCloneOnStart(true);
        return properties;
    }
```